# Sending mails with headers AWS Lambda SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I'm sending mails from AWS lambda using ..

```
const params = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: ["xxx@xxx.com"]
    },
    Header : {
      "Reply-To" : "hello@gmail.com"
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Html: {
          Charset: "UTF-8",
          Data: htmlBody
        },
        Text: {
          Charset: "UTF-8",
          Data: textBody
        }
      },
      Subject: {
        Charset: "UTF-8",
        Data: "My title"
      }
    },
    Source: "xxx.com"
  };

  // Create the promise and SES service object
  const sendPromise = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: "2010-12-01",region: 'us-east-1' })
    .sendEmail(params)
    .promise();
```

But, its giving `UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Headers' found in params`

How to send headers properly with SES & Lambda,
I need to use `reply-to` mainly.

Answer (score 0):

SES `sendEmail` function parameters have no `Header` key. I believe that you are looking for key called `ReplyToAddresses` which is a list of email addresses.

So you can replace

```
Header : {
    "Reply-To" : "hello@gmail.com"
},
```

in your code with

```
ReplyToAddresses: [ "hello@gmail.com" ]
```

Comment: Supporting doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendEmail.html